# Spring Webflux Custom WebFilter Causes HTTP 200 response for all open endpoints

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webflux

I'm developing a Spring Boot Webflux application that has a custom WebFilter that does just-in-time user creation based on the Principal object derived from the request.

The WebFilter works fine for endpoints that require authentication.  But for endpoints that don't need authentication, anything matching the pattern below returns HTTP 200 - even if the endpoint doesn't exist.  Also, the endpoint doesn't appear to be called.

My Security configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(
            ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(swx -> corsConfiguration()))
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .securityMatcher(new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(
                        ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/actuator/**")))
                .authorizeExchange((authorize) -> authorize
                        .pathMatchers("/foo/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyExchange()
                        .authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(ors -> ors.jwt(jwt -> {}))
                .build();
    }
```

My WebFilter:

```
@Component
public class JITUserFilter implements WebFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JITUserFilter.class);

    private final UserService userService;

    public JITUserFilter(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange,
                             WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
        return serverWebExchange.getPrincipal().flatMap(p -> {
            Optional<String> email = Optional.empty();
            if (p instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken) {
                email = Optional.of(((JwtAuthenticationToken)p).getToken().getClaimAsString("https://my-app.example.com/email"));
            }
            Optional<User> userOpt = userService.findUserByExternalId(p.getName());
            if (userOpt.isEmpty()) {
                logger.info("No existing user found; creating new with externalId {}", p.getName());
                User user = new User();
                user.setExternalId(p.getName());
                user.setEmail(email.orElse(null));
                userService.createUser(user);
            }
            return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
        });
    }
}
```

I have a POST endpoint at `/foo/bar` that I expect to log some messages and return a dummy response when it gets hit, but all I get when making a post to this endpoint is a 200 OK response.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that what's happening here is that if there is no `Authentication` header passed, then the `serverWebExchange.getPrincipal()` in the web filter is an empty `Mono`.  If that's the case, the entire block gets skipped, which causes the `HTTP 200` response.

Solution is to add this at the end:

```
.switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange)))
```

so that the rest of the filter chain continues.